# React Native : react native undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._lazyCallableModules

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to try react native android app development, and got this error.

This is my index.android.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>First Try</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found this issue on react-native's repo： https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14933#issuecomment-314150944， try change your `babel-preset-react-native` in `package.json` to 2.0.0 and then run `npm install` and do `watchman watch-del-all`, then try start running the project again.

Not sure if this would be the issue, but try it out:
change `import React from 'react';` into `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

And then change `export default class App extends React.Component` into `export default class App extends Component`