# React Native this._lazyCallableModules[name] is not a function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, facebook-login

I had a fully functioning react native app, and I tried to install the Facebook Login button. I followed these instructions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios

There is a known issue using react-native link to connect the Facebook SDK to the project, and so I tried linking it manually. I could not get the Facebook Login to work, and now when I use **react-native run-ios**, my app just shows a black screen!

As a test, I used create-react-native-app to create a new app, and I launched it, and I'm getting this error:

this._lazyCallableModules[name] is not a function (MessageQueue.js 155:11)

Since I'm not sure what MessageQueue is and this is a brand new app, I'm not sure how to undo the damage I've done.

Has anyone experienced this, or do you at least have some idea of how I can go about resetting my react setup?

If I haven't given enough relevant information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662468/react-native-react-native-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-lazyca?s=2%7C1.6088) and it's working well so far.

Downgrade the `babel-preset-react-native` package from `2.0.1` to `2.0.0`. The command is `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.0.0`. Use the `--save` flag if you want to store it to your `package.json`.

Comment: I use "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0" and  "react-native": "^0.47.2" and get this error too

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest React Native, clean & build solved it for me.